# Dynamically type a text inside a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My aim is to be able to type a text on the fly (*that can be resized and move*) inside a given div element, so I have created a textbox that is appended where i clicked.

```
$('div').click(function(e){

    var top = e.clientY+'px';
    var left = e.clientX+'px';
    $('div').append('<input type="text">');
    $('input[type="text"]').css({'position' : 'absolute','top' : top,'left' : left});


});
```

problem is that, when I was about to type a text, it won't let me and it created a new textbox instead.

Heres a [fiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ct8eL7/) the problem.

Is there any clean approach as to what I wanted to do? Any suggestions is greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.focus()` on input additionally.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p2ct8eL7/4/

JS:

```
$('div').click(function (e) {
    var top = e.clientY - 20 + 'px';
    var left = e.clientX - 20 + 'px';
    var i = $('<input type="text">'); //Store the input in a variable.
    $('div').append(i);
    i.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': top,
        'left': left
    }).focus(); // modify the current input instead of all.
});
```

Comment: this works. but what if i need a new line of text, the current text dissapears. any furhter suggestion? thanks

Comment: thank you very much! that's definitely what i want. though this definitely is not yet done but i will open another question for that specific problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

When clicking, simply remove the click-Handler or check if there already is an input, so that your code can be skipped. Put this at the top of your event handler function:

```
if($(this).find('input[type="text"]').length > 0){
   return;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2ct8eL7/2/

Comment: tried this but it wont let me create a new textbox. and sorry for not clarifying further.but i need it to stay after the text is created and i should be able to create a new textbox if i need a new line of text.

Comment: What do you do in order to get rid of your old textbox? This approach expects you to remove it instead of hiding it. :)